# Rails render error code with jsonapi-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json-api

I want to render error `code` property, as JSON API specification describes, with `jsonapi_errors` method in `jsonapi-rails` gem. How could I set the code property in error object?

PS I'm using `ActiveInteraction` gem in combination with `jsonapi-rails`.

Answer (score 0):

To render the error this syntax **jsonapi-rails** gem supports
***render jsonapi_errors: { detail: resource.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity*.**

Comment: There's an open issue on jsonapi-rails gem requesting support for specifying error codes: https://github.com/jsonapi-rb/jsonapi-rails/issues/86